# Querying from two tables in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables where I have students details and other table consists of the details of TAs. Tables are as follows:

```
Students(B#, first_name, last_name, status, GPA, email, bdate, dept)
TAs(B#, ta_level, office)
```

Now, For each TA from the CS department, find his/her B#, first name, last name, and birth date. I have tried the following query:

```
select Students.B#, Students.FIRST_NAME, Students.LAST_NAME, Students.BDATE
from Students INNER JOIN TAs ON Students.B# = TAs.B#;
```

but I have to get only those TAs who are studying in Computer Science. I am using Oracle DB. How will I add another condition after inner join?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Ambiguous column name perhaps?  If so, you just need to give an alias to the `B#` field -- `select TAs.B# ...`.  If that's not the case, please provide sample data and expected results.  Also I'd highly recommend using explicit `join` syntax versus commas in your `from` clause.

Comment: You need to do an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

> For each TA from the CS department

Is there a table or a column specify if a student is studying Computer Science ? however as per your question it seems from the department you can know that.
You can do the below:

```
select Students.B#, Students.FIRST_NAME, Students.LAST_NAME, Students.BDATE
from Students INNER JOIN TAs ON Students.B# = TAs.B#
where Students.dept='CS' -- or computer science depending on the value.
```